# Does the cross-platform System.IO.Ports.SerialPort library work on Android with FTDI UART chips? (e.g FT232R)?

Tags: android, .net, serial-port, uart, ftdi

I am trying to write a cross-platform GUI to control hardware for use on both Windows and Android. I am using an FTDI serial cable. When the cable is plugged in, the SerialPort.GetPortNames() identifies the cable as
`/dev/ttyUSB0`

When I try to open the connection to this port, I get an exception with the following message:
`Access to the port '/dev/ttyUSB0' is denied.`

I have also tried the following strings:
 `'ttyUSB0', 'USB0', 'dev/ttyUSB0'`

I can confirm the “Serial USB Terminal” software from the Play Store works fine on my Android device. I can connect and send strings without problems.

**Is this cross platform?**
Information about Port.IO.SerialPort ability to support Android.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/95749

**My Questions:**

- Should IO.Ports library V9.0 work with this setup?
- If not, will it be supported in the future? (If not, I may abandon Android support and just use the Windows FTDI DLL)
- Am I missing some magic Android permissions fiddle?
- Have you got .NET IO.Ports library working with FTDI UART on another Android setup?

**This is as far as I got:**
My feeling is that it Open() falls back on Linux, and expects drivers to be installed as per:
https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/AN_220_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_Linux-1.pdf

Feel free to share your experiences here. When I saw ‘GetPortNames()’ working on my phone, I got so excited but never got any further. I was so close!

**My Setup:**

- Android Platform: Samsung Galaxy S7, Android Version 8.0.0
- FTDI Chip: FT232R  (Cable is a TTL-232R-3V3)
- In C# using Visual Studio Version 17.9.2
- Visual Studio debugger identifies ‘Target local device SM-G930T (Android  8.0, API V26)
- Using SerialPort in .NET System.IO.Ports library 9.0.0-preview.1.24080.9 from
  https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/
- Android "Serial USB Terminal" used
  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_usb_terminal&hl=en_GB&gl=US

**Debugging:**
The Exception message is as follows:

```
Access to the port '/dev/ttyUSB0' is denied.
 at System.IO.Ports.SafeSerialDeviceHandle.Open(string portName)
 at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream..ctor(string portName, int baudRate, Parity parity, int dataBits, StopBits stopBits, int readTimeout, int writeTimeout, Handshake handshake,
            bool dtrEnable, bool rtsEnable, bool _1 , byte _2)
 at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open()
 at .. < then into my project code>
```

I think the exception message relates to this line in the .NET SerialPort library
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1d1bf92fcf43aa6981804dc53c5174445069c9e4/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SafeSerialDeviceHandle.Unix.cs#L29

Comment: I'm curious what makes you believe the .NET SerialPort library supports Android?  its just the .NET framework siting on top of Windows OS. For reference, generally any Android app supporting USB-serial is probably using this library or a variation of it: https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

Comment: System.IO.Ports is compatible with .NET 6 and .NET Standard 2. So the library is supposed to be cross-platform. And indeed, it contains Android specific code: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.IO.Ports/src/System/IO/Ports/SerialPort.Unix.cs#L16

Comment: @MorrisonChang I've updated the question following your feedback. (That's one comprehensive library!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to the developer and got the following response:

> Hey, yes the System.IO.Ports implementation uses the /dev/tty
> functionality common to many Unix systems. Unfortunately Android by
> default has a SELinux policy preventing access to that device:
> https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/86619#issuecomment-1843502371
>
> The same would happen if you try to `fopen("/dev/ttyUSB0", "r+")`​
> in regular native C code.
>
> If you can't root the device or have custom Android then as far as I
> know you're out of luck and need to rely on custom libraries/drivers.

**Summary**
It will work if you are targeting a custom Android platform or a rooted phone (after some fiddle), but not for a phone running stock ROM.